# Develop windows app like OneDrive app in windows 8.1

Tags: wpf, windows, winforms, onedrive

The OneDrive app in Windows 8.1, can let user choose "Make available offline" or "Make available online-only".

When user choose "Make available online-only", user still can see the data in windows file explorer, but the data not really store in local disk.
When user double click the data, OneDrive will download data from cloud to local, if computer doesn't have net, user can't open data.

Have any way to display data in windows file explorer even the data is not store in local disk...I can't find any solution or API can let me use...

Comment: I'm no OneDrive expert, but I can theorize how they have done that. I'm guessing that the "online-only" file is simply just the basic information (like filename and ID) of the file that's on the server, when you double click to open the file, OneDrive goes off and uses the basic information to download the appropriate file for use. But that's just my guess.

Comment: I found Windows 8.1 has new data format called "smart files". 
But this feature will be remove on Windows 10... 
So we can't develop the app like OneDrive anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though Windows itself may not support it the same way with built-in handling, you should still be able to code up a solution similar to what you were looking for.  From what I can tell the "smart files" that OneDrive/SkyDrive were using could also be called "Placeholder Files" now.  They're basically just NTFS Reparse Points with a custom Reparse Tag Identifier associated to the file types.

See here: [Reparse Points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365503(v=vs.85).aspx)

It should be noted however since it was mentioned above, that even though the old Reparse Tag identifier was deprecated, they seem to be re-implementing a version of the Placeholder files for Windows 10. Recent builds included new "ONEDRIVE" reparse tag identifiers.

See here: [new Reparse Tags (twitter)](https://twitter.com/h0x0d/status/827576761579823105)

Comment: @Elliot I feel the above solution answers the question of how this would be accomplished both in existing versions of Windows as well as into the future, can you please mark the solution as solved if it meets your requirements?